# videoview.getDuration() returns -1

Tags: android

i am trying to develop a android app for playing a video from raw folder. am using custom control options. the getduration() returns -1 so i cant set max value to my seekbar. here is my code

```
private MediaController mediaController;
private VideoView videoView;
public TextView duration;
private int timeElapsed=0,finalTime=0;
private int forwardTime=2000, backwardTime=2000;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();

}
public void initialize()
{
    videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);


    mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


    String
    uri1="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.materialdesign;

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri1);

    videoView.setMediaController(null);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
    R.raw.materialdesign);
    Log.e("finalTime", "" + finalTime);
    finalTime = videoView.getDuration();
    Log.e("finalTime", ""+finalTime);
    Log.e("finalTime", ""+videoView.getDuration());
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    seekBar.setMax(finalTime);
    seekBar.setClickable(false);

    videoView.requestFocus();


}
```

Answer (score 12):

In case you haven't found a solution, `VideoView.getDuration()` will return -1 if the video is not in playback state. The video is not in playback state until it has been prepared. So calling `VideoView.getDuration()` directly after setting the URI does not guarantee that the video has been prepared.

I found this by looking at the source of VideoView:

```
@Override
public int getDuration() {
    if (isInPlaybackState()) {
        return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The solution is to set an OnPreparedListener to your VideoView, and obtain the duration once the video is prepared. You can then use `VideoView.getDuration()` or `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`, which are nearly identical.

Solution:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        int duration = mp.getDuration();
        int videoDuration = videoView.getDuration();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onPrepared: duration=%d, videoDuration=%d", duration,
            videoDuration);
        }
        seekBar.setMax(videoDuration);
    });
```